# Get total count per ID change

Tags: t-sql

how can I get a total count of sheets per change of sheet

example:

```
select sheetID,
       ..
from SomeTable
```

results look something like this:

```
sheetID
-----------
1000
1000
1000
1000
3000
3000
3000
```

so I want something like this:

```
select sheetID,
       count(sheetID) as TotalsheetCount
from SomeTable
```

I just don't know how to break the count up per change of sheetID.

So I'd end up with this essentially:

```
sheetID   TotalsheetCount
--------  -----------
1000          4
1000          4
1000          4
1000          4
3000          3
3000          3
3000          3
```

so 4 is because there are 4 1000s, 3 because there are 3 3000s.  I am wanting to repeat the total count for that sheetID for each row, even though it's repeating, I want to provide that.

UPDATE, here's what I did per the replies but I'm getting way too many results now as compoared to the count where I did not add that partition count before

```
   select MainTable.sheetID,
           COUNT(SomeTable.sheetID)OVER(PARTITION BY SomeTable.sheetID) AS TotalSheetCount
           table2.SomeField1,
           table2.SomeField1
    from MainTable
        join (select distinct Sales.SalesKey from SomeLongTableName_Sales) sales on sales.SheetKey = MainTable.sheetKey
        left outer join Site on MainTable.SiteKey = Site.SiteKey
        join Calendar on sales.Date >= Calendar.StartDate
             and sales.Date < Calendar.EndDate
        group by SomeTable.sheetID
```

the joins and stuff is more realistic to my real query but formatted for this post to hide real field and table names.

Comment: So you want to repeat the sheetID for the number of times it occurs in your SomeTable, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT sheetID,  COUNT(sheetID) AS TotalsheetCount
FROM dbo.SomeTable
GROUP BY sheetID
```

> I am wanting to repeat the total count for that sheetID for each row,
>   even though it's repeating, I want to provide that

If you're using at least SQL-Server 2005, you can use a CTE with `COUNT` + [`OVER`-clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx), otherwise use a sub-query:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT sheetID,  
      COUNT(sheetID)OVER(PARTITION BY sheetID) AS TotalsheetCount
   FROM SomeTable
)
SELECT sheetID, TotalsheetCount FROM CTE
```

Comment: I added the partition but now I get way too many records in the entire result set using count(*) vs. before I added that count with partition.  I should be still getting the same count

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: I'm not sure, is this not the expected result(repeating)? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e6e15/2/0

Comment: had to add distinct to my CTE, it works now...thanks.  Much faster since I'm using a CTE also.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`GROUP BY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) clause in a subquery to select the counts:

```
SELECT sheetID,
       count(sheetID) as TotalsheetCount
FROM SomeTable
GROUP BY sheetID
```

This would make your whole query look like this:

```
SELECT t.sheetID,
       counts.TotalsheetCount
FROM SomeTable t,
    (SELECT sheetID, count(sheetID) as TotalsheetCount FROM SomeTable GROUP BY sheetID) counts
WHERE t.sheetID = counts.sheetID
```

Comment: that's it?  it'll change by itself per change of sheeID?

Comment: @CoffeeAddict Sorry, misread your question at first. The edited answer should work for you, however.

Comment: +1, would use an explicitly stated join though (or whatever it is called).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a group-by expression:

```
select sheetID,
       count(*) as TotalsheetCount
from SomeTable
group by sheetID
```

Is that it?

DC